# What's the most useful thing you've done in less than 50 lines of Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Clojure seems likes it might have a good shot at being a popular Lisp.  I was wondering how many people have actually adopted it to solve some of the small, yet real, problems that they have encountered.  Since Clojure doesn't have an entry in [Pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net), I thought that it would be great if people posted their small solutions to problems that they've solved in Clojure.

Comment: I can.  Is that what I should do with a question like this?

Comment: How many characters per line?  As you know, a line in Clojure can go on forever...

Comment: Yeah, 50 is arbitrary # too.  No hard fast rules.  Just trying gather lots of "small" useful Clojure programs that people have used to solve some sort of problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This prints a weather forecast via [Yahoo! Weather](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

```
(ns weather
  (:use (clojure [xml :only [parse]] [zip :only [xml-zip]])
        (clojure.contrib duck-streams str-utils pprint)
        (clojure.contrib.zip-filter xml)))

(defn fetch-xml [uri]
  (xml-zip
   (parse
    (org.xml.sax.InputSource.
     (java.io.StringReader.
      (slurp* (java.net.URI. (re-gsub #"\s+" "+" (str uri)))))))))

(defn yahoo-weather
  ([loc-code] (yahoo-weather loc-code "c"))
  ([loc-code unit]
     (let [rss (fetch-xml (str "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=" loc-code "&u=" unit))]
       (if (= (text (xml1-> rss :channel :item :title)) "City not found")
         "City not found.  Go to http://weather.yahoo.com/, search for your city, and look in the URL for the location code."
         (let [[units loc wind atm ast] (map #(xml1-> rss :channel (keyword (str "yweather:" %)))
                                             ["units" "location" "wind" "atmosphere" "astronomy"])
               conditions (xml1-> rss :channel :item :yweather:condition)
               date (re-find #"\d+:\d+.*" (xml1-> rss :channel :item :pubDate text))
               fors (xml-> rss :channel :item :yweather:forecast)]
           (cl-format true
"Weather for ~a, ~a (~a)
    Temperature: ~a\u00B0 ~a
     Wind Chill: ~a\u00B0 ~a, ~a ~a
     Conditions: ~a
       Humidity: ~a%
      Barometer: ~a ~a
 Sunrise/Sunset: ~a / ~a

Forecast:
~{  ~{~a: ~a. Hi ~2d, Lo ~2d.~}~^~%~}
"
                      (attr loc :city) (attr loc :region) date
                      (attr conditions :temp) (attr units :temperature)
                      (attr wind :chill) (attr units :temperature) (attr wind :speed) (attr units :speed)
                      (attr conditions :text)
                      (attr atm :humidity)
                      (attr atm :pressure) (attr units :pressure)
                      (attr ast :sunrise) (attr ast :sunset)
                      (map #(list (attr % :day)
                                  (attr % :text)
                                  (attr % :high)
                                  (attr % :low))
                           fors)))))))
```

For example:

```
user> (weather/yahoo-weather "CAXX0328")
Weather for North Vancouver,  (10:00 am PDT)
    Temperature: 14° C
     Wind Chill: 14° C, 8.05 kph
     Conditions: Light Rain Shower
       Humidity: 88%
      Barometer: 1018 mb
 Sunrise/Sunset: 6:01 am / 8:32 pm

Forecast:
  Thu: Few Showers. Hi 18, Lo 12.
  Fri: AM Showers. Hi 19, Lo 12.
nil
```

Comment: Bragging comment, I know, but allow me for once to take a position. How can people like this language? it's stylistically unreadable :(

Comment: Anything is readable if you spend enough time with it.  Proper syntax highlighting helps (Stack Overflow's highlighter script chokes on Lisp).  Many people have a color scheme that fades the parens into the background a bit.  This code is also an odd example because of the huge string I had to left-justify (and because I was trying to cram everything into 50ish lines).

Comment: I wish to rebut. the language that must not be named (brainf*k) stays unreadable in any case, regardless of how much time you spend on it. However, I tried to import your script in vim with proper highlighting. It helped, but not much. The main problem about functional languages is that they are intrinsically deeply nested, and deep nesting is by many parts (GUI design, refactoring, code smells) reported as a warning sign for bad usability or code quality. The functional approach is cool (would never leave out map() from python, ever!), but it must be used with moderation, IMHO.

Comment: Lisp is admittedly dense, but that lets you put more code on-screen at once, which makes it easy to scan through lots of code quickly.  So there are pluses and minuses.  There are also structures that you grow to recognize; `let` forms always look a certain way for example.  This is all largely subjective and I can't remark on your experiences, but Lisp was painful for me to read at first too, and after a year or two I have no problems.  I've read many other people's experiences who gasped in horror at Lisp at first, but eventually grew to like or even prefer its syntax.  YMMV of course.

Comment: Thank you Brian, this has made its way into my utilities, so I do not have to decontextualize by opening up Dashboard or, gasp, look out the window to know what it's like outside!

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that /you/ have trouble reading Lisp. I, nor Brian, nor 99% of the people who have actually /used/ Lisp on #Clojure and #lisp on freenode have a problem reading Lisp.

Comment: @StefanoBorini If your code is not readable, refactor it ; apart from the usual tools to improve code readability and usability (routine/module extraction, code formatting, etc.), there are ways around deep nesting in Clojure, like the threading macros (`->`, `->>`, etc.). In general, Lisps are better at this than most languages, because macros puts you in control of your compiler and give you more power to develop DSLs than most meta-programming features.

Answer (score 9):

Not really particularly useful by itself, but the idea is similar to JSON in Javascript--you can move Clojure data structures to and from the file system. Adopted from [Practical Common Lisp's Database](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html) example:

```
(ns storage (:import (java.io File PushbackReader FileReader FileWriter)))

(defn load-data
  "Loads data from the given file."
  [filepath]
  (do
    ;; the let block creates the file if it doesn't exist
    ;; reader throws an exception if there's no parsable data struct
    (let [file (new File filepath)]
      (if (not (.exists file))
        (do
          (.createNewFile file)
          (doto (new FileWriter filepath) (.write "{}") .close))))
    (read (new PushbackReader (new FileReader filepath)))))

(defn dump-data
  "Exports data structure to a file."
  [filepath data]
  (doto (new FileWriter filepath) (.write (str data)) .close))
```

Example usage:

```
user=> (dump-data "test.dat" {:a [1 2 3] :b "hello" :c true})
#<FileWriter java.io.FileWriter@186df0f>

user=> (load-data "test.dat")
{:a [1 2 3], :b "hello", :c true}
```

Certainly beats writing your own (complex) save mechanism for your program. I'm sure reading purely from a string is possible just by changing some of the readers provided via Java.

Comment: When this was written I guess [spit](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/spit) and [slurp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp) didn't exist (or might not have, I'm not solid on my history). But they do now, so, as a warning to anyone reading this: don't use this code anymore.

Comment: And now there is [`load-file`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/load-file).

Answer (score 6):

**99 Bottles of Beer**

```
(defn bottles [n & [capitalize]]
  (str (if (> n 0) n (if capitalize "No more" "no more"))
    " bottle" (if (= 1 n) "" "s") " of beer" ))

(defn bot-wall [n & cap] (str (bottles n cap) " on the wall"))

(defn sing
  ;  Default is 99 times.
  ([]  (sing 99))
  ([stock]
    (doseq [i (range stock -1 -1)]
      (printf "%s, %s.\n%s.\n\n"
        (bot-wall i true) (bottles i)
        (apply str
          (if (> i 0)
            ["Take one down and pass it around, " (bot-wall (dec i))]
            ["Go to the store and buy some more, " (bot-wall stock)]
          ))))))

(sing)
```

http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-clojure-1996.html

Comment: …for certain values of "useful," I guess.

Answer (score 6):

This creates a thumbnail from an image.  The image can be a local File, remote URL or anything else [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) can read (thanks Java!).  Output can be any image format `javax.imageio.ImageIO` can write.

```
(use '(clojure.contrib java-utils))
(defn make-thumbnail
  "Given an input image (File, URL, InputStream, ImageInputStream),
   output a smaller, scaled copy of the image to the given filename.
   The output format is derived from the output filename if possible.
   Width should be given in pixels."
  ([image out-filename width]
     (if-let [format (re-find #"\.(\w+)$" out-filename)]
       (make-thumbnail image out-filename width (nth format 1))
       (throw (Exception. "Can't determine output file format based on filename."))))
  ([image out-filename width format]
     (let [img (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read image)
           imgtype (java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_RGB)
           width (min (.getWidth img) width)
           height (* (/ width (.getWidth img)) (.getHeight img))
           simg (java.awt.image.BufferedImage. width height imgtype)
           g (.createGraphics simg)]
       (.drawImage g img 0 0 width height nil)
       (.dispose g)
       (javax.imageio.ImageIO/write simg format (as-file out-filename)))))
```

Create a JPG thumbnail from a local PNG:

```
(make-thumbnail (java.io.File. "some-image.png") "thumb.jpg" 150)
```

Create a GIF thumbnail from a remote JPG:

```
(make-thumbnail (java.net.URL. "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/justice-league-small.jpg") "small.gif" 250)
```

Comment: My code works on the JVM without any other dependencies, which is its main appeal.  I needed this for a website I was making.  It's easier to do this than to validate URLs myself and do system calls and check return values etc.  The Java versions throw exceptions when they fail and deal with standard Java objects I can do other things with (pass easily into other libraries etc.).  I also tried the ImageMagick bindings for Java but they were pretty painful.

Answer (score 6):

The most useful thing I've written for myself in Clojure is the almost trivial function:

```
(defn tally-map
 " Create a map where the keys are all of the unique elements in the input
   sequence and the values represent the number of times those elements
   occur. Note that the keys may not be formatted as conventional Clojure
   keys, i.e. a colon preceding a symbol."
  [aseq]
  (apply merge-with + (map (fn [x] {x 1}) aseq)))
```

I use this all the time in the work I do. Very useful for histograms.

[Brian Carper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23070/brian-carper) was kind enough to suggest the following improved form of the function.

```
(defn tally-map [coll]
  (reduce (fn [h n]
            (assoc h n (inc (or (h n) 0))))
          {} coll))
```

Comment: A function called `frequencies`, added to Clojure 1.2, now provides this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure probably has a power function, but I was really excited when I figured this out:

```
(defn pow [base exp] (reduce * (replicate exp base)))
```

Comment: You're right, it's in java.lang.Math:  `(defn pow [base exp] (Math/pow base exp))`

Comment: cool and it handles arbitrary precisions numbers rather than just Math.pow() which only handles doubles.....

Comment: @mikera: but arbitrary precision numbers only as the base, with only integer as an exponent, if I understand right.

Answer (score 2):

Writing Swing apps, the JMenuBar stuff is always annoying.  Thanks to dorun/map it's much easier:

```
(let [menus
[
 {:name "File" :mnemonic \F
  :items
  [
   {:name "Open" :mnemonic \O :fn file-open}
   :separator 
   {:name "Exit" :mnemonic \x :fn file-exit}
   ]
  }

 {:name "Help" :mnemonic \H
  :items
  [
   :separator 
   {:name "About..." :mnemonic \A :fn help-about}
   ]
  }
 ]

menu-fns
(into
 {}
 (mapcat
  (fn [menu]
    (map
     (fn [item] [(:name item) (:fn item)])
     (:items menu)))
  menus))

ui-frame
(proxy [JFrame ActionListener] ["UI Frame"]
  (actionPerformed
   [event]
    (let [command (.getActionCommand event)
      menu-fn (get menu-fns command)]

      ;; Handle menu commands
      (if menu-fn
    (apply menu-fn [this]))
      ))
  )
]

(defn new-menu [listener]
  (let [menubar (JMenuBar.)]
(dorun
 (map
  (fn [x]
    (let [menu (JMenu. (:name x))]
      (.setMnemonic menu (int (:mnemonic x)))
      (.add menubar menu)
      (dorun
       (map
    (fn [item]
      (if (= :separator item)
        (.addSeparator menu)
        (let [menu-item
          (if (:mnemonic item)
            (JMenuItem. (:name item) (int (:mnemonic item)))
            (JMenuItem. (:name item)))]
          (.addActionListener menu-item listener)
          (.add menu menu-item))))
    (:items x)))))
  menus))

menubar))
```

Right now I don't need sub-menus, but it's a trivial change to `new-menu` to get them.  Also adding icons, active/inactive state, etc. is just more fields in `menus`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code really was meant for me and nobody else. I threw it together in twenty minutes the other day for a course on Markov processes. I certainly found it useful. I used it to convince the professor that my theoretical analysis of a problem was correct. Honestly, the cool bit (I think!) really is just the first function, `sample`. I use a function like that in many of my projects, and somehow when hacking this up in a hurry I stumbled onto my best solution yet.

```
(defn sample
   "Samples once a discrete random distribution defined by
   a vector. E.g., (sample [0.25 0.2 0.1 0.45]) should output
   '0' 25% of the time, '1' 20% of the time, etc."
   [p]
   (let [r (rand)]
      (count (take-while #(< % r) (reductions + p)))))
(defn transition
   "Given a transition matrix and a history vector, returns
   the history with an additional time step added."
   [m h]
      (conj h (sample (nth m (last h)))))
(defn process-gen
   "Takes a transition probability matrix, initial state
   probabilities, and a function.
   The initial state probs should take the form [p .. q].
   The function should accept the full process history
   and return true if the process should stop.  
   Returns a function of no arguments that returns a full
   simulated history of the process."
   [m i f]
   (fn [] (loop [h [(sample i)]] (if (f h) h (recur (transition m h))))))
(defn transition2
   "Given a transition matrix and the current state, returns
    a sampled state for the next time step."
   [m s]
   (sample (nth m s)))
(defn lazy-process
   "Takes a transition probability matrix, initial state
   probabilities, and a function.
   The initial state probs should take the form [p .. q].
   Returns a function which, when run, produces an infinite
   lazy list sampling the process."
   [m i]
   (fn [] f
      ([] (f (sample initial)))
      ([s] (let [i (transition2 m s)]
            (cons i (lazy-seq (f i)))))))
```

Removing comments:

```
(defn sample [p]
   (let [r (rand)]
      (count (take-while #(< % r) (reductions + p)))))
(defn transition [m h]
      (conj h (sample (nth m (last h)))))
(defn process-gen [m i f]
   (fn [] (loop [h [(sample i)]] (if (f h) h (recur (transition m h))))))
(defn transition2 [m s]
   (sample (nth m s)))
(defn lazy-process-gen [m i]
   (fn [] f
      ([] (f (sample initial)))
      ([s] (let [i (transition2 m s)]
            (cons i (lazy-seq (f i)))))))
```

Example use:

```
user=>(def squirrel-matrix [[0.8797 0.0212 0.0981 0.0010]
[0.0382 0.8002 0.0273 0.1343]
[0.0527 0.0041 0.8802 0.0630]
[0.0008 0.0143 0.0527 0.9322]])
user=>(def my-process (process-gen squirrel-matrix [1 0 0 0] #(and (> (count %) 1) (= 0 (last %)))))
user=> (/ (reduce + (map (comp dec count) (repeatedly 1000000 my-process))) 1000000.)
5.820319
user=> (let [hs (reduce + (filter #(> % 1) (map (comp dec count) (repeatedly 1000000 my-process))))] (/ (reduce + hs)) (count hs)))
5002699/120880 ; ~41.386
```

These two numbers answer, via rather excessive simulation, two different interpretations of the question [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=SpI8nqVRye8C&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I must confess that I cleaned up my code a little for y'all. The day I wrote this was the day I discovered Clojure allowed Unicode in symbol names. I may have gone a *little* overboard in modifying the language. ;-) So...those first three functions actually look like this in my file!

```
(Λ σ [p] (let [r (rand)] (|| (take-while #(< % r) (∮ + p)))))
(Λ Δ [Ξ ξ] (⊞ ξ (σ (§ Ξ (last ξ)))))
(Λ Π [Ξ i ω] (λ [] (⟳ [ξ [(σ i)]] (⇒ (ω ξ) ξ (⟲ (Δ Ξ ξ))))))
```

Comment: Could you share the redefinitions you used for the "cryptic" version ?

Comment: @nha It's been a long time. But by comparing the functions, I get the following replacement map: `{defn Λ,  count ||, reductions ∮, conj ⊞, nth §, fn λ, loop ⟳, if ⇒, recur ⟲}`

Answer (score 1):

A more serious answer this time:

I'm often frustrated by the REPL stacktrace function only displaying eight lines. So this is now in the development file for all my projects:

```
(defn stack
   [n]
   (clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace (clojure.stacktrace/root-cause *e) n))
```

I want `argmin` and `argmax` *all the time*.

```
(defn argmin
   ([f x] x)
   ([f x y] (if (< (f x) (f y)) x y))
   ([f x y & more] (reduce (partial argmin f) (argmin f x y) more)))
(defn argmax
   ([f x] x)
   ([f x y] (if (> (f x) (f y)) x y))
  ([f x y & more] (reduce (partial argmax f) (argmax f x y) more)))
```

And, finally, for evaluating algorithms robustly I use this function on datasets a lot:

```
(defn kfolds
   "Given an integer k and a collection of data, this
   partitions the data into k non-overlapping collections,
   then returns a list of length k, where the ith item is
   itself a list of two items: 
      (1) the union of all but the ith partition
      (2) the ith partition.
   If (count data) is not divisible by k, a few points (< k)
   will be left out."
   [k data]
   (let [total (count data)
         fold-size (int (/ total k))
         folds-test (take k (partition fold-size fold-size [] data))
         folds-train (map #(apply concat %)
                        (map #(take (dec k)
                                 (drop %
                                       (cycle folds-test)))
                           (range 1 (inc k))))]
         (map list folds-train folds-test)))
```